# I can't ever get Regex Right

Tags: regex

I have a query string I'm trying to remove a query string parameter. What I currently have is

`date=(.*)&`

But this will remove anything to the last &. I only want to remove to the first occurance of the &.

So this is how it should work:

`date=5%2F13%2F16&tab=1&a=b` = `tab=1&a=b`

But mine is doing this:

`date=5%2F13%2F16&tab=1&a=b` = `a=b`

I think I probably need something around the & but I read the regex stuff and I just get more confused.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/cA6cI0/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it lazy, use:

```
date=(.*?)&
```

Comment: Or, make the dot match everything but `&`: `date=([^&]*)&`

Comment: I fing hate regex. Spend much longer than needed everytime. Thanks

Comment: @Mr.Llama since I'm lazy, I prefer to type less ;)

Comment: Lastly, what if there is no &. What if it's the last paremeter. I think maybe Mr. Llama's will, going to test.

Comment: @Leeish - If there is no final `&`, the pattern will not match.  It explicitly expects a `&` at the end.  You could replace it with `(?:&|$)` which will match (but not capture) either the next `&` or the end of line.

Comment: Thank you. That looks to solve it. Now I have `date=(.*?)(?:&|$)`

Comment: Sorry wouldn't let me at the time.